# Matlab-How can I make the graph of (exist plot) keep moving as long as the audio file is playing?

Tags: matlab

[image]

```
t=[1/Fs:1/Fs:length(y)/Fs];
 axes(handles.axes1)
 plot(t,y)
```

Comment: I'm using guide